# fetch date from datetime column in sql

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a Product table.I want fetch date from datetime column.
I wrote this query.

Query code is here

```
SELECT Date = CONVERT(DATE, Date) FROM Product
```

Query is running sql server management studio and returning the correct date but when called from C# the query runs and returns a result but it returns datetime rather than just the date.

So for example if the query:

```
SELECT Date = CONVERT(DATE, Date) FROM Product
```

returns 09-02-16 in management studio

the C# code

```
SqlDataAdapter adr;
        adr = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Date = CONVERT(DATE, Date) FROM Product", conn);
```

returns 09.02.2016 00:00:00

What I would like the C# code to return is: 09-02-16

Please help.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I don't have an error. Query code running result: 2015-11-23. But c# code is running result : 23.11.2015 00:00:00

Comment: I assume you are connecting to an sql server. s your connection open?

Comment: True code is SqlDataAdapter adr; adr = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, Date, 120), 10) from Product", conn);

Answer (score 1):

based on you comment you may want to try:

```
SqlDataAdapter adr;
        adr = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [Date] = convert(VARCHAR,[Date], 5) FROM Product", conn);
```

The `convert(datetime,[date], 5)` will ensure you are returning the result as DD-MM-YY

Comment: no error. But result is : 23.11.2015 00:00:00 in the c# code. I want just fetch date.

Comment: @AndroidDvlpr Ok I edited my answer to return a varchar rather than a date datatype. That should work as C# data types are not strongly typed you can have it as varchar.

Comment: @AndroidDvlpr I see you unaccepted the answer didn't it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this `SELECT CONVERT(date,[Date]) as date FROM Product`

Comment: I tried. But not running in c# code. But running sql query. Please help.

Comment: is your connection open?

Comment: Kamran Farzami my connection is open

Answer (score 0):

Date is a keyword in SQL, so I would avoid using it:

```
var adr = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT CAST([Date] AS DATE) AS OnlyDate FROM Product", conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is certainly wrong. either you want to do

```
SELECT CONVERT([DATE], 102) FROM Product
```

(OR) declare a variable and store the data there like

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME;
SELECT @Date = TOP 1 CONVERT([DATE], 102) FROM Product
```

Assuming you have a column named `DATE` and you will have to use a proper format string unless you are passing format string as parameter. Though your query is bit unclear.

Comment: IMHO there is no reason to declare a variable.

Comment: @FabianBigler, yes but my assumption is that OP trying to store the data to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment:

> I don't have an error. Query code running result: 2015-11-23. But c#
>   code is running result : 23.11.2015 00:00:00

I assume that your query is already working properly.

**However, the format of the date is different!**

So all you need to do is to convert the DateTime in your wished [format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).

Note: Per default the culture of your thread is based on the settings of your computer (In your case, it's dd.MM.yyyy). The result of the query on SQL Management Studio is depending on the column you are selecting (In your case: yyyy-MM-dd).

Answer (score 0):

> c# code is running result : 23.11.2015 00:00:00

How are you seeing this and where? In the debugger in VS? On the screen?

It is probably just formatting based on your culture (the one set on your PC). You are probably not understanding the difference between viewing the string representation in C# of a DateTime object, which can be formatted based on your locale, and the default ISO formatting in Sql Server.

Also there is no such thing in c# as just a date object, its always a date with time (DateTime) although the time component will then have 0 values for the time aspects of the object.

In short it is probably working the way it should.

Answer (score 0):

True code is here :

```
 SqlDataAdapter adr; 
    adr = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, Date, 120), 10) from Product", conn);
```